# ThreadStateException in Winform especially in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

According to MSDN, ThreadStateException happens mainly because new Thread create a OpenFileDialog's tool in Main Thread;

```
private void button_FileExercise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    fileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    }
}
```

ThreadStateException happens at "if", Therefore, How can I solve the program like it, THX!

Comment: Does this happen when you click the button? Or are you calling the method from some other thread?

Comment: It happens when I click the button. However, when I set Function Main() with [STA] type, It works well. When mult-Thread used, how can I solve this problem

Comment: Any thread that displays UI *must* declare itself STA.  And run a dispatcher loop, Application.Run().  Rock-hard requirements, the exception just reminds you that you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without setting **[STAThread]** you might have to go through Thread-Apartment-Safe to achieve this with single thread

[This link explains how](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/841702/Thread-Apartment-Safe-Open-Save-File-Dialogs-for-C)